# Does $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{|\sin(n)|}} $ converge?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I am trying to determine whether the series $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n^{|\sin(n)|}} $ converges or not. The difficulty is in that every now and then $\sin(n)$ will be very close to zero making the corresponding term in the series close to $\pm 1$. If I could show that these outlier terms eventually get much smaller than $1$, or if there are about as many positive such terms as negative ones then the series would converge, but I'm not sure how to approach that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Denjoy-Koksma inequality?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/282259/is-the-series-sum-n-sin-nn-n-convergent/282290#282290

Comment: @Jack D'Aurizio Isn't that a bit heavy-handed? $\pi$ is irrational, so there are infinitely many $n$ with $\{n/\pi\}<1/n$, i.e. $|\sin(n)|<\pi/n$.

Comment: @ProfessorVector: you are right, that is enough. I was thinking to the more subtle case $$\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{1}{n^{1+|\sin(n)|}}.$$

Comment: I think I figured it out. By what @ProfessorVector said there will be infinitely many terms in the series satisfying $$ \frac{1}{n^{\frac{\pi}{n}}} < \frac{1}{n^{|\sin(n)|}} <1 $$ in magnitude. Since the left side of the inequality tends to 1 as $n$ tends to infinity, there will be infinitely many terms arbitrarily close to 1 in magnitude. Because of this the series diverges.

Comment: Thanks everybody!